# Folder Redirection Issue

Tags: windows, active-directory, folder-redirection

I am currently having a rather urgent issue with folder redirection. We attempted to move the files from the old server to the new server and everything works except documents. It appears to create two documents folders for the user, and for some reason the one it actually uses is empty (does not contain the transferred files.) After further investigation I determined that one of those folders is actually named "Documents" The one labeled "Documents" is the folder that actually contains the users files. How can I remedy this situation? I'm afraid that come Monday I'm going to have a couple thousand students with no files. This process worked fine for my test accounts.

[image]

Old Server: 2008 R2 New Server: 2012 R2

We edited the users to change their home folder location and create their individual folders and then copied and pasted their files within explorer.

Comment: When you change the Folder Redirection path Windows will move the redirected folders to the new path upon user logon. That's why you're seeing two sets of folders. My suggestion would be to delete everything in the Redirected Folders share and allow Windows to move the files when the users login.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by Joe, what you're probably seeing is Windows moving the redirected folders to a new path when the user logs in.  It's also possible, but less likely, that one of those is just a junction point that you copied when you used the GUI (!) to do this.  Either way, it shouldn't cause the problem you fear, but it will probably result in slow logon times for your users when Windows tries to move all those `My Documents` folders on login.

For future reference, [use robocopy for this kind of thing](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).  It's actually what Microsoft utilities like the file server migration toolkit use in the background.